# Issues using IntRect in SFML. Can not pass constructors to IntRect like all tutorials show

Tags: c++, sfml

```
taa.left = 0;
taa.top = 0;
taa.height = playerSpriteSize.y;
taa.width = playerSpriteSize.x;
player.setTextureRect(taa);


player.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 50, 50));
```

The taa part works but the later part does not. Why does it not let me assaign the rect directly?

So setting values individually seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it pretty fast. It uses vectors in this latest version...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).